# How to extract a month from date in csv file?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I'm trying to get an output of all the employees who worked this month by extracting the month from the date but I get this error:

```
month = int(row[1].split('-')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

A row in the attendance log csv looks like this:

```
"404555403","2020-10-14 23:58:15.668520","Chandler Bing"
```

I don't understand why it's out of range?
Thanks for any help!

```
import csv
import datetime

def monthly_attendance_report():
"""
The function prints the attendance data of all employees from this month.
"""
this_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
with open('attendance_log.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        month = int(row[1].split('-')[1])
        if month == this_month:
            return row

monthly_attendance_report()
```

Comment: Your logic works fine with a list; try checking whether you're iterating through the CSV file correctly (i.e. try printing out `row`).

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me. The problem will be probably in processing the csv file, because csv files have in most cases headers, which means that you can't split header text. So add slicer [1:] to your for loop and ignore first line with header:

```
for row in content[1:]:
```

And processing date by slicing is not good at all, too. Use datetime module or something like that.